# Select a proxy from the listbox (IDHTTP)

Tags: delphi, proxy, listbox, idhttp

I am preparing an application. IDHTTP: Using the Get method. But there are some problems. I want to create a list of Proxy and click listbox items (Proxy address) IDHTTP added. Sorry i little know English.

My codes;

```
procedure TForm1.CheckBox1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
if CheckBox1.Checked then
begin
LabeledEdit1.Enabled:= true;
LabeledEdit2.Enabled:= true;
IdHTTP1.ProxyParams.ProxyServer:=LabeledEdit1.Text;
IdHTTP1.ProxyParams.ProxyPort:=StrToInt(LabeledEdit2.Text);

CheckBox1.Caption:='Kendi IP adresimi kullan.';

 end
 else
begin

LabeledEdit1.Enabled:= false;
LabeledEdit2.Enabled:= false;
IdHTTP1.ProxyParams.ProxyServer:='';
IdHTTP1.ProxyParams.ProxyPort:=StrToInt('0');

CheckBox1.Caption:='Proxy kullan.';

end;
end;

procedure TForm1.BitBtn2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
IdHTTP1.Get(Edit1.Text);
MessageDlg('Mission complated.', mtinformation,[mbOK],0);
end;
```

I want;

I add Listbox1 Proxy.. Later.. Click Listbox1 item. Later.. BitBtn2 click.

Thanks.

Comment: You already have the logic needed to assign a Proxy to `TIdHTTP`, so what is the actual problem you are having? Just change your code to use `TListBox` instead of `TLabeledEdit` when assigning the Proxy information.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, I *think* the question is about how to add all available proxy servers to a listbox and allow the user to select the one used in `TIdHTTP.ProxyParams` from that listbox.

Comment: There are many proxy. 1.1.x.2.1:80, 1.2.x.x.5:60 ..... as.. one by one in order to avoid? Listbox1.itemadd(Proxy + : +Port) as?... Sorry..

Comment: IdHTTP1.ProxyParams.ProxyServer and ProxyPort:=Listbox1.item[1] combine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Listbox1.Items.Add('1.1.x.2.1:80');
Listbox1.Items.Add('1.2.x.x.5:60');
...
```

.

```
procedure TForm1.Listbox1Click(Sender: TObject); 
var
  I: Integer;
  S: String;
begin 
  I := Listbox1.ItemIndex;
  if I <> -1 then
  begin 
    S := Listbox1.Items[I];
    IdHTTP1.ProxyParams.ProxyServer := Fetch(S, ':'); 
    IdHTTP1.ProxyParams.ProxyPort := StrToInt(S); 
  end 
  else 
  begin 
    IdHTTP1.ProxyParams.ProxyServer := ''; 
    IdHTTP1.ProxyParams.ProxyPort := 0; 
  end; 
end;
```

.

```
procedure TForm1.BitBtn2Click(Sender: TObject);        
begin        
  IdHTTP1.Get(Edit1.Text);        
  MessageDlg('Mission complated.', mtinformation,[mbOK],0);        
end;
```

Comment: Thanks but.. [Error] Unit1.pas(139): Undeclared identifier: 'Fetch' error?

Comment: @user1424940 you basically parse the string in the form "ip:port", so you need to grab the ip, the part before ":" and then the port, the part after ":", from what I understand, fetch grabs everything before ":" from "s" variable and leaves the part after ":", while dumping it, it's a nice exercise to do on your own.

Comment: I added IdGlobal uses. Problem is solved. if error 407 then showmessage() ?

Comment: `TIdHTTP` handles 407 internally. It will trigger the `OnSelectProxyAuthorization` and `OnProxyAuthorization` events as needed until the `MaxAuthRetries` number of attempts have been made. If any other HTTP error occurs, or `MaxAuthRetries` is reached, then `TIdHTTP` will raise an exception that you can catch in your code.